Ardiuno Bluetooth connection from Node.js
I have a HC05 module connected to arduino UNOr3, and a basic bluetooth-serial-port nodejs library to send a single line of data so I can make sure it works. Although, my bluetooth module is connected to my nodejs and saying its sent, there is nothing being received on the arduino end. I have tried moving the ports, i.e. rx and tx pins to 0,1 as well, but there was no luck.
JS:
var BluetoothSerialPort = new (require("bluetooth-serial-port").BluetoothSerialPort)();
const arduinoMACAddress = 'XXXXXXXX'; //assume that the MAC address is correct (privacy reasons, I don't want to include it)

BluetoothSerialPort.findSerialPortChannel(arduinoMACAddress, function(channel) {
    BluetoothSerialPort.connect(arduinoMACAddress, channel, function() {
        console.log('Connected to Arduino');
        BluetoothSerialPort.write(Buffer.from('test', 'utf-8'), function(err, bytesWritten) {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error writing data:', err);
            } else {
                console.log(`Sent ${bytesWritten} bytes to Arduino`);
            }
        });
    }, function() {
        console.log('Cannot connect to Arduino');
    });
});

Ardiuno side:
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define rxPin 10
#define txPin 11

// Set up a new SoftwareSerial object
SoftwareSerial mySerial =  SoftwareSerial(rxPin, txPin);

void setup()  {
    // Define pin modes for TX and RX
    pinMode(rxPin, INPUT);
    pinMode(txPin, OUTPUT);
    
    // Set the baud rate for the SoftwareSerial object
    mySerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    if (mySerial.available() > 0) {
        Serial.println("Connected");
        mySerial.read();
    }
}


The Arduino code would not show anything because you have only initialised the SoftwareSerial port, not the serial port that you are hoping to read text from. Oddly this does not throw an error in the compilation process. In the code below I have initialised the port at 9600 baud, and also added lines so that whatever is received from your HC05 module is also displayed (and a line to confirm that both ports have been set up).
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define rxPin 10
#define txPin 11

// Set up a new SoftwareSerial object
SoftwareSerial mySerial =  SoftwareSerial(rxPin, txPin);

void setup()  {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    // Define pin modes for TX and RX
    pinMode(rxPin, INPUT);
    pinMode(txPin, OUTPUT);
    
    // Set the baud rate for the SoftwareSerial object
    mySerial.begin(9600);
    
    Serial.println("Ready");
}

void loop() {
    if (mySerial.available() > 0) {
        Serial.println("Data available");
        char a = mySerial.read();
        Serial.print(a);
    }
}

